# How do I load a CSS file with HTMLTextWriter

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

Using HTMLWriter I've been able to load individual pieces of CSS with the following:

```
protected static void FixHeaderStylesHeight(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Style);
    writer.Write(".ms-siteicon-img { max-height: 80px; }");
    writer.RenderEndTag();
}
```

This is now getting more complicated and I'd like to load an external CSS file into the page, basically, if this was HTML I would use the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stdtheme.css" />
```

How can I duplicate this kind of functionality using HtmlTextWriter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an IDE in front of me, but I believe I've done something like this in the past:

```
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, "/stdtheme.css");
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/css");
writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Link);
```